# Android Google API -This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key

Tags: android, google-api

Although I have followed all the steps mentioned in google developer log book, like

1. creating a project
2. enabling required APIS
3. generating SHA1 digest for mobile application cetificate
4. creating public access key

but upon executing my request am getting following error,

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Dont know which thing am missing, any help guys.

Thanks,
Techfist

Answer (score 1):

I also followed the rules, even contacted some people I know at Google Places (which asked me to look at StackOverflow... where I hadn't found any solution previously), just to find out a bit later that my server was somehow banned/blocked by google (I used the server as a client to visit Google, and it told me that it considered me as a robot once in a while).

When checking with same key and other IP address not banned/blocked, it was ok. Now I just have to figure out how to unban my server as I don't plan to use my browser to issue API requests.